# Multiple Stack Navigators on one screen

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

How do you go about showing multiple **Stack.Navigators** on one **Drawer.Screen** with React Navigation 5.

Let's say I have 2 types of products: Mobile Phones and Tablets on my Dashboard **Drawer.Screen**. Mobile Phones and Tablets represent a separate **Stack.Navigators**, how do I show both of them on the same screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way :

```js
export const DrawerNavigator = props => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <DrawerScreen {...props} />}
      initialRouteName={'HomeScreen'}
      drawerPosition={'right'}
      drawerStyle={{width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
      screenOption={{backBehavior: 'order'}}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="App"
        component={isMobile ? MobileStackNavigator :     tabletStackNavigator}
        options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};
```